# Vertical cell alignment

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, styling

I am trying to make a weekly schedule table with the div tag. Here is the sample code for each day:

```
<% times.each do |time| %>
  <% d = worker.working_on_day(Date.new(time.year,time.month,time.day).cwday - 1) %>
  <div style="height: <%= d.duration.to_i * 4 %>px; ">
  ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, I wanted to dynamically adjust the height of the cell based on the duration. But the heights does not align properly. For example, a cell with a duration of 30 minutes is slightly smaller than two cells of 15 minutes. How can I properly adjust the height to align the cells properly?

Comment: Do you have any paddings or borders?

Comment: It seems like using an actual table, with each cell representing 15 or 30 minute increments might be better for this. Then you can just `colspan="X"` on cells to allow them to span over multiple time slots.  If that won't work for you can you provide some additional information, is this just top aligning one row of items or what?

Comment: Probably there are some CSS rules affecting your cells. Could you add some CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="height: <%= d.duration.to_i * 4 %>px; padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0;">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked, but now I can barely make out the table.

Comment: You should move those CSS definitions to a central place: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5629471